# Using libcurl on visual c++ to login to a website

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm using libcurl to open/save a remote file and parse html files and everything is going great.

I was wondering if it's possible to use c++ and curl to login to a website (not a ssl one) and from there maybe manipulate the html that is generated?

I would love to do that within my executable (not to use php).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the [libcurl examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) ?

Comment: yes i've looked and i figured it out thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured there is a way if anyone stumbles upon this. there's an example here:
http://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1078

the website has a some what black hat approach but the example provided was useful.